# '-[__NSCFNumber row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb416910'

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift, unrecognized-selector

I am implementing a UITableViewController, it looks like the following:

```
import UIKit

class FriendsListTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var friends = String[]()
    var profileImages = String[]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        friends = ["Joe Georgio", "Mafio Ambroso", "Tony Mozarotto", "Bob Jaymes", "Matthew Hall"]
        profileImages = ["logo60pt", "checkmark", "OrangeSplashScreen", "twittericon", "OrangeSplashScreen2"]

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return friends.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
        let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FriendTableViewCell

        cell.friendNameLabel.text = friends[indexPath!.row]
        cell.friendProfileImageView.image = UIImage(named: profileImages[indexPath!.row])

        return cell
        // Configure the cell...
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */


    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            //indexPath!.delete(indexPath!.row)
            tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!.row], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
```

It is crashing at the line that states:

```
tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!.row], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

..after pressing the delete button provided by Apple for each TableView cell.

I am guessing I need to modify the friends, profileImages String arrays? Where can I do this without it crashing? Or is there a delegate method I am supposed to be using?

Edit: Here is the error message (without the call stack):

> 2014-07-10 20:04:56.404 TableViewController Test[3070:109022]
>   -[__NSCFNumber row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb30a1b0 2014-07-10 20:04:56.408 TableViewController Test[3070:109022] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber row]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb30a1b0'

Comment: indexPath! is not supposed to have a not "!" after

Comment: How can I access which row is selected then? It shouldn't be nil, if it is, then I need to modify the data source accordingly.

Comment: er heh, I assumed it was C... ignore my

Comment: Please look at the method parameters..you are looking at all of the code minus appDelegate (default methods), and the subclass of UITableViewCell that I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending an `NSNumber` (row) instead of an array of `IndexPath`s which is what that method takes as its first parameter.

you want:

```
tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

Comment: I modified it to the code you posted and received: _2014-07-10 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)._

Comment: The modification I made to your code is I unwrapped the indexPath to be [!indexPath] and no @. Do I call the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` method?

Comment: You have to update your model to match the row you are deleting before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.  That is, you must remove that element from the `friends` array.